# Hand in job reference from previous employer to current employer

Tags: references, germany

### Background

I recently switched jobs and started working for another company (Let's call the previous company "**company A**" and the current company I work at "**company B**").
Both companies are located in Germany.

I didn't have any job reference from company A upon applying at my current job at company B.

During the interview, we spoke about my tasks at company A. Company B offered me a job after the interview, but didn't ask for any reference from company A.

After I handed in my resignation at company A, I asked for and got a job reference from company A.

### My question

On the one hand, the job reference I got from company A is (I think) quite favorable and might underline some of the qualities/qualifications my current manager at company B might not even realize I have, based on the single interview we had.

On the other hand, I don't want to come across over-eager or to give the impression that my previous job at company A was in any way more challenging or rewarding than my current position.

Is it for some reason a bad idea or bad form to hand in the reference with company B, even though they never asked for it?

Comment: If you don't have a job reference from the previous employer, how do know it was favorable and how will you hand it in?

Comment: I re-read and edited the question. Never post questions on SE on a monday morning before you had the first two cups of coffee...
I hope the question is clearer now.

Comment: Close vote retracted and downvote removed.

Comment: Location? In some places the idea of a job reference is formal, in other places they are informal.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I've added the location to the question.

Answer (score 5):

In general for jobs, if a document has not been explicitly asked for, it is not important from the policy perspective of the company. If a document has not been explicitly asked for do not provide it. Stay within the policy framework.